# „Zusätzlich dazu“ - mit oder ohne Komma?

Tags: comma

Darf dieser Satz das Komma behalten? Muss es sein?

> Zusätzlich dazu, werden 10 Häftlinge freigelassen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das Komma muss weg.
Der Teil davor enthält kein wie auch immer geartetes Verb. Es ist einfach ein Satzadverbial genau wie "leider" oder "Trotz des widrigen Wetters auf der Bergspitze".

Answer (score 0):

Meiner Meinung nach ohne, da das ja  ein Satz mit einem Thema ist, wo keine Abgrenzung sinnvoll erscheint IMHO.

Aber eventuell hast Du nicht den ganzen Satz geschrieben und es steht noch was davor, das ein Komma hier erfordert.

Comment: Der Originalsatz ist „Zusätzlich dazu, werden [...].“, es kommt also nichts davor. „dazu“ bezieht sich auf den vorherigen Satz.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, Du sagst nicht, was in dem vorigen Satz steht, wieso? Ich kann das nicht erraten,sorry. Aber noch eine Variante, wenn der ursprüngliche Satz wäre:__Zusätzlich dazu, es werden 10 Häftlinge freigelassen__  , dann wäre IMHO ein Komma unbedingt notwendig.

Comment: Bei welchem Thema würde eine Abgrenzung sinnvoll erscheinen?

Comment: Ein Komma ist also dazu da, innerhalb eines Satzes eine thematische Abgrenzung zu schaffen? Das, finde ich, ist auch mal eine interessante Definition...